# lightroom photo export with sRGB profile

Tags: color-management, color-spaces, srgb, adobe-rgb

I work on a calibrated Full gamut monitor, and switch between lightroom and Photoshop for my editing. Both are set to work in AdobeRGB color mode. After all edits are done, i go to export, and set the file format to JPG, image quality to 100 and filetype to sRGB. Unfortunately the exported image is way oversaturated when viewed in Windows.

I have been taught that setting the sRGB profile on export converts the image in sRGB and should appear correct in the browsers/viewers, but for some reasons it behaves as if the image is exported in adobeRGB. The file properties show sRGB too.

What am I misunderstanding?

EDIT: the file appears correctly in Firefox, and oversaturated in Edge.

shouldnt it appear properly in edge if exported as srgb?

EDIT2: as requested here is a screen of the export settings
[image]

EDIT3: as requested a screenshot of my Photoshop color settings: NOTE: The monitor color profile has been created using spyder5 elite.
[image]

also here is a sample.. top is Edge, bottom is Firefox.
[image]

Comment: Maybe a screenshot of your export settings would help.

Comment: added info and screenshot.

Comment: actually i assume that your color management settings are wrong (hint: you can't work in AdobeRGB in Lightroom). So you're over correcting. Maybe you can add a sample image and a screenshot of your color management settings of PS? (and your monitor profile setting)

Comment: Working space **should not** be your monitor profile [that is compensated automatically as it's drawn to screen & shouldn't be in your workflow otherwise]. It should be Adobe RGB or for web sRGB. Colour management should be all set to Preserve.

Comment: @Tetsujin: looks like an answer?

Comment: @ths - I think it might be, I'll add it. I wasn't sure to start with, but it does look like the source of the output mismatch. I've only recently got this whole workflow thing firmly in my head... & that's the kind of error I used to make - PS workflow setup is really not as obvious as it looks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the main error is that your Working Space is set to your monitor profile.

The monitor profile is actually adapted "live" as it's drawn to screen & should not be part of your workflow.
You should always check that the correct monitor profile is in the drop-list for that tab, but you should select your actual intended gamut there - AdobeRGB for 'high colour' or sRGB for web.

Colour Management should be set to Preserve embedded profiles.

This ensures that the profile embedded in the original photograph remains the single source from which all modifications are made & you don't keep unnecessarily recalculating to different gamuts.

At Export is the only time you should replace that profile - this also preserves the original profile in the master copy untouched.
Your Export settings look fine - the error was earlier in the workflow.

I have to admit, I only learned this myself quite recently; being [what I thought was] an old hand at Photoshop, but a newbie at actual photography. It was quite a revelation when I did.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that some applications are color managed, and some not.  in your example, firefox is a color managed browser, so it is smart enough to see the sRGB profile and convert it to AdobeRGB (or more precisely to the profile of your monitor which is close to AdobeRGB).  Edge I guess is not.  Photoshop is smart, so images should appear fine there.

This is normal behavior with non-color managed applications, and is one reason so much work for the web is done in sRGB -- most people (at least originally) did not have color managed browsers, and also had roughly sRGB monitors, so it just worked, kind of like having all the people in the room speak English (or French or whatever). The alternative is to have all the people have a translator (i.e. all be color managed) and then each can speak any language and they can still understand.

To work correctly for you, you should identify programs for use that are color managed, and try to stick to them.  The issue is the wide gamut monitor and other applications not how Lightroom created the image.  If you exported it as AdobeRGB it might be closer for you, but someone else (many if not most other people on the web) would see it incorrectly.  Once everyone started using different gamut monitors, without color managed applications, there ceased to be one right answer.  sRGB is still the most common, but it is getting more confusing as more people get wide gamut monitors.

Comment: thanks for your answer. There is still something I am missing: I understand that Edge is not color managed, thus shows the image wrong. Up to now i Always thought "work in a as wide range as possible, and then convert when exporting. this will clip some colors but at least you can work on full color". I thought that saving as sRGB would clip the colors... like the "export for web" in Photoshop. What do i have to do with my image so that i can be sure that everybody sees it like i see it in lightroom? (obviously not taking into account monitor calibration etc..)

Comment: I think you are thinking of "wider" as a superset, i.e. that all the same colors as sRGB are in AdobeRGB, just more in addition.  The problem is they are different.  Let's take (00,50,50) which is teal in sRGB.  To get the same color in AdobeRGB (if I used this calculator correctly, and not sure) I would need to send (38,67,67).  If there's a color management layer that change is automatic.  Without one, it sends (0,50,50) and your monitor displays some other, unexpected (if similar) color.

Comment: To elaborate a bit further: The AdobeRGB space is wider because each color represents a shade further apart in AdobeRGB than it does in sRGB.  So AdobeRGB can represent more colors, but fewer shades of a given color (at least on average).

Comment: Yep, thats clear.. but what is not clear is how I can actually export a image in a way that it does not need a color profile.. that it already is saved a normal 8 bit jpg and everybody can see it correctly.. on any browser..

Comment: The answer for "everybody" is you cannot, since different people have different monitor setups. The answer for "most" people is sRGB, as most people do not (yet) have wide monitors.  Even those that do may not use the same wide color space.  The answer for "everybody" is to convince all application makers to use color management.